# Можно ли в телеграм боте на одну inline кнопку сделать две ссылки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, link

При написании своего бота столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно сделать на одну inline кнопку переход сразу на две ссылки. Можно ли так сделать? Тщательно поискав информацию в интернете, не нашёл никакого ответа на данный вопрос. Также интересует, возможно ли впринципе сделать переход сразу на несколько ссылок с помощью любой библиотеки или реализации на Python? Возможно посоветуете какие-либо библиотеки, или примерные пути решения ситуации. Заранее ,спасибо

Comment: А что делают те ссылки? Со стороны пользователя как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: @gil9red Это ссылки на сайты , к примеру: при нажатии кнопки, в браузере у пользователя открываются сразу две ссылки, допустим одна на ruSO , вторая на enSO

Comment: У inline кнопки в параметре url только один может быть, получается нельзя. Только сделать две кнопки

Comment: @gil9red, поэтому я в конце попросил привести ещё возможные способы решения с помощью любых других библиотек, главное, чтобы на Python